# Асинхронность и кеширование в swift

Tags: swift

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые!
Пытаюсь навоять приложение для сайта (api тоже пишу сам). Вывести данные получилось в tableView, однако он сильно тормозил при скроллинге. Методом комментирования кусков кода, понял, что беда в загрузке изображений по прямой ссылке. Вот как я делал это ранее:

```
let imgURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: strImageURL)!
let imgData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL)!
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: imgData)
```

Картинки грузились, но tableView жутко тормозил. Поискав в интернете нашел несколько советов, что надо бы организовать кэширование изображений скачанных и сделать асинхронную загрузку. Вот только я не совсем понимаю как это сделать. Можете подкинуть пару понятных мануалов? (можно на английском). И если считаете эту затею не очень хорошей, то посоветуйте, как грамотно грузить изображения с сервера по прямой ссылке, чтобы не затормозить приложение для ios?

Comment: Не изобретайте велосипед. Используйте например эту библиотеку: https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage асинхронная загрузка и кэширование картинок там есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как неоднократно писал, отдавайте в `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  `cell`, а данными заполняйте асинхронно.

Для загрузки изображений можете использовать любую библиотеку, которая подойдет под Ваши требования, к примеру, [из поиска GitHub](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=image%20language%3ASwift&ref=simplesearch&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93)